# Twistd - Telnet - Python server, Java Client, client never receives string until connection closed, when all strings concatenated and sent together

Tags: java, python, twisted, telnet

I've got a server written in python running twisted (twistd), and a client written in Java.  The idea is that we'll be able to send Strings of encoded data between clients via this server.  However, we're finding that clients never send a string to the server (it's never logged on the server as having been received).  Does anyone have any ideas?

I've included the code for the client and server below.

Client:

```
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1025);
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println("Before Read");
    System.out.println(is.read());
    System.out.println("After Read");
    os.write("Hello from java!".getBytes());
```

Server:

```
class MyChat(basic.LineReceiver):
__opponent = None

def connectionMade(self):
    print "SLOG"
    self.factory.clients.append(self)
    print "SLOG 1"
    self.factory.notInGame.append(self)
    print "SLOG 2"
    while (len(self.factory.notInGame) >= 2):
        x = self.factory.notInGame.pop(0)
        y = self.factory.notInGame.pop(0)
        x.__opponent = y
        y.__opponent = x
    print "SLOG FINISH YAY"

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    print "SLOG Lost a client!"
    self.factory.clients.remove(self)
    if (self.__opponent == None):
        self.factory.notInGame.remove(self)
    else:
        self.__opponent.__opponent = None
        self.factory.notInGame.append(self.__opponent)

def lineReceived(self, data):
    print "SLOG Sender data received"
    if self.__opponent == None:
        self.transport.write("E0") # not in game
        print "SLOG E0"
        return
    self.__opponent.transport.write(data)


from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.application import service, internet

factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = MyChat
factory.clients = []
factory.notInGame = []

application = service.Application("chatserver")
#internet.TCPServer(1025, factory).setServiceParent(application)
reactor.listenTCP(1025, factory)
```

Any help appreciated - thanks

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LineReceiver` accumulates data in a buffer and calls the `lineReceived` callback when it receives a full line.  By default lines are terminated by the byte sequence `"\r\n"`.

It looks like your Java application sends `"Hello from java!"`.  Since it does not send `"\r\n"` `LineReceiver` never decides to call `lineReceived`.

Comment: Thanks - that was the issue - I literally found it a couple of minutes ago.  The problem I am now having is that Java read only wants to read one bytes!